# XHTML2PDF Django [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, django

I have deployed my django application with XAMPP & mod_wsgi. Everything was good before I deployed my application. However after I deployed it, the pdf dowloand function won't work and return error.

Here's the snapshot of my code

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict, file_name):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    context = Context(context_dict)
    html  = template.render(context)
    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        response = http.HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' %(file_name,)
        response.write(result.getvalue())
        return response
    return http.HttpResponse('We had some errors<pre>%s</pre>' % cgi.escape(html))
```

Here's the error

```
[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Here's the line of code that cause error

```
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
```

The Exception Location:

```
C:\Python27x32\Lib\socket.py in create_connection, line 571
```

Here's the code of my wsgi.py

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/xampp/htdocs/ghb/ghb/wsgi.py"

    <Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/ghb/">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static/ C:/xampp/htdocs/ghb/static/

    <Directory c:/xampp/htdocs/ghb/static/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's the [Error Log](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7963925/error.log)

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant traceback can be found in your `error.log` beginning at line 400. From this traceback, it seems to me that your HTML contains a URL (perhaps a link to an image?) that doesn’t work (perhaps it points to `localhost` and works on your desktop, but not on the server?); xhtml2pdf tries to fetch that URL (perhaps to include the image inside the PDF?) and fails. Check the contents of your `html` variable (the HTML code that you pass to xhtml2pdf) for broken `http:` or `https:` links. By following filename+line references from the traceback (like `File "C:\\Python27x32\\lib\\site-packages\\xhtml2pdf\\parser.py", line 448`), you can determine more precisely which element xhtml2pdf is choking on.